# Cannot Insert formulas when export excel in OZ Report Designer

Tags: excel, oz

now I am using OZ Report Designer for Forces, and I have a question: can I insert formulas into cells when I export to Excel? After export, the result shows normally, but when I click on a cell, it shows the formulas. I tried to research and learn about Oz Report, but no result; the information is so little. Everyone who has experience, can you give me a suggestion or any keywords for this? Thank you so much.